# Direction of scroll RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, scroll, android-recyclerview

Can I detect the direction of scroll when I add the on scroll listener to my recycler view?

The code is as follows:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            switch (recyclerView.getScrollState()) {
                case RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING :
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) relativeBaseLayout.getLayoutParams();
                    if(layoutParams.weight < 1.0f) {
                        SlideAnimation slideAnimation = new SlideAnimation(layoutParams.weight, 1.0f, relativeBaseLayout);
                        slideAnimation.setDuration(250);
                        relativeBaseLayout.startAnimation(slideAnimation);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

I want this function to work only if I scroll down.

Currently it'll work on both scroll up and down. What changes do I make?

I do not want to implement the `onScrolled()` method since that will be called after the scroll has finished. I want to detect it during the scroll.

What am I missing here?